# how do not push all the array not have this product

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

for example i have this code i used this json:

```
"food": {
        "appetizers": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "image": "../image/calammari.png",
                "title": "rings",
                "price": 11500,
                "ingredient":[{
                    "id" : "0001",
                    "name": "avocado"
                },
                {
                    "id" : "0001",
                    "name": "tomato"
                }
            ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "image": "../image/food2.png",
                "title": "bang bang",
                "price": 10000,
                "ingredient":[{
                    "id" : "0001",
                    "name": "eggplant"
                },
                {
                    "id" : "0001",
                    "name": "cucumber"
                }
            ]
            }
```

from this json file if the array my access equal tomato , just i want to display the food that have tomato.

so i used this html:

```
  <div ng-repeat="appetizer in appetizers ">
                        <div>
                            <img ng-src="{{appetizer.image}}" />
                           <div >
                                <p >
                                    {{appetizer.title | uppercase}}
                                </p>
                            </div>
```

and this javascript :

```
  var myAccess = ["tomato"];

      $scope.test = [];
      var appetizer = $scope.appetizers;
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.appetizers.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < $scope.appetizers[i].ingredient.length; j++) {

            if ($scope.appetizers[i].ingredient[j].name === myAccess) {

// what should i write here

            }
          }
      }
      return null;    }
```

sorry its about this if someone can help please !!

so myAccess = tomato , and should read the first of the appetizer that in the ingredient tomato , and i want to push just the ingredient that have tomato .

Comment: If you don't want to show the items those not having tomato ingredient, just pop from that array.

Comment: i have million of these array , if i have many array but just i put these

Comment: You need to get only the data, which have a name called 'tomato' ? am i right?

Comment: You should define the variable $scope.text if you haven't already done so before like this - const $scope.test = [];

Comment: no not only tomato , sometimes other item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could be helpful for you

```js
var app=angular.module("myapp",[]);
app.controller("test_ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.appetizers = [];
$scope.temp={
 "food": {
  "appetizers": [
    {
     "id": 1,
     "image": "../image/calammari.png",
     "title": "rings",
     "price": 11500,
     "ingredient":[
      {
       "id" : "0001",
       "name": "avocado"
      },
      {
       "id" : "0001",
       "name": "tomato"
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "id": 2,
     "image": "../image/food2.png",
     "title": "bang bang",
     "price": 10000,
     "ingredient":[
      {
       "id" : "0001",
       "name": "eggplant"
      },
      {
       "id" : "0001",
       "name": "cucumber"
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
}
            
            
            var myAccess = ["tomato"];

      
      var appetizer = $scope.temp.food.appetizers;
      for (var i = 0; i < appetizer.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < appetizer[i].ingredient.length; j++) {
            if (appetizer[i].ingredient[j].name === myAccess[0]) {
                $scope.appetizers.push(appetizer[i]);

            }
          }
      }
         
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="test_ctrl">
<div ng-repeat="appetizer in appetizers ">
    <div>
        <img ng-src="{{appetizer.image}}" />
       <div >
            <p >
                {{appetizer.title | uppercase}}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
       
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) in the following way:

Items that have some of the ingredients

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"image":"../image/calammari.png","title":"rings","price":11500,"ingredient":[{"id":"0001","name":"avocado"},{"id":"0001","name":"tomato"}]},{"id":2,"image":"../image/food2.png","title":"bang bang","price":10000,"ingredient":[{"id":"0001","name":"eggplant"},{"id":"0001","name":"cucumber"}]}];
const myAccess = ['avocado', 'tomato'];

console.log(
  data.filter(
    (item) => 
      item.ingredient.some(
        (ingredient) => myAccess.includes(ingredient.name)
      )
  )
);
```

Items that have all of the ingredients:

```
data.filter(
  (item) => 
    myAccess.every(
      (ingredient)=>
        item.ingredient.some(
          (i)=>i.name===ingredient
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: that's cool but i want it in my own javascript any other way please

Comment: @bryanghsb I added the case where you want to filter on 'tomato' or 'avocado' (myAccess is an array of strings). If you want it in your own script then I suggest you write it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comment, check the below JS that might sort out your problem.

```
function myFunction() {
    var myAccess = "tomato";
    $scope.test = [];
    var appetizer = $scope.appetizers;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.appetizers.length; i++) {
        var flag = 'false';
        for (var j = 0; j < $scope.appetizers[i].ingredient.length; j++) {
            if ($scope.appetizers[i].ingredient[j].name === myAccess) {
                flag = 'true'; // Flag to check whether it's exist
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag == 'false') {
            appetizer.splice(index, i); // Pop that item if it's not exist
        }
    }
    $scope.appetizers = appetizer; // Re-assign
}
```

Introduced variable `flag` that'll tell whether that array contains `myAccess` value or not. Based on that, I removed that index from that array variable `appetizer`. Finally, this array variable will replace scope variable.

I haven't checked the code. So, Just try or implement from yours using this logic if it suits.

EDIT - My code looks not much effective while comparing @HMR answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Push appetizers into your array like this.

```
function myFunction() {
var myAccess = ["tomato"];

  $scope.test = [];
  var appetizer = $scope.appetizers;
  for (var i = 0; i < appetizer.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < appetizer[i].ingredient.length; j++) {

        if (appetizer[i].ingredient[j].name === myAccess) {

             // what should i write here
             $scope.appetizers.push(appetizer[i]); // additional code here.
        }
      }
  }
  return null;    }
```

Comment: If myAccess were to be tomato and avocado you'll end up with the item called 'rings' twice. Array filter would be far more suitable for this task.