# How to search result in array in specific timestamp in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the array with the different timestamp and based on that each timestamp there is some data related to this timestamp.
for e.g. I have the data of whole day in array in that array there are the different timestamp and based on each timestamp there are some records based on this timestamp. So I want to search the records in array only from 4am to 6am.

```
    var object = {"main": [
    {"timestamp": "1am","name": "name 1"},
    {"timestamp": "2am","name": "name 2"},
    {"timestamp": "3am","name": "name 1"}, 
    {"timestamp": "4am","name": "name 2"},
    {"timestamp": "5am","name": "name 1"}, 
    {"timestamp": "6am","name": "name 2"},
    {"timestamp": "7am","name": "name 1"}, 
    {"timestamp": "8am","name": "name 2"},
    {"timestamp": "9am","name": "name 1"}, 
    {"timestamp": "10am","name": "name 2"}
    ]};
```

Comment: You should provide relevant code examples so we can better help you. However, it sounds to me like [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is what you need.

Comment: Map your timestamp to a number `Number(timeStamp.replace(/[ap]m/,'')) + (timeStamp.includes('pm')?12:0)` filter on this number with larger and smaller compare functions like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53850431/1641941)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mentioned the values of timestamp as "4am", "5am" for readability. In general, those values will be integer values of EPOCH Unix timestamp in milliseconds.

So the approach is simple to use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var object = {"main": [
    {"timestamp": 1,"name": "name 1"},
    {"timestamp": 2,"name": "name 2"},
    {"timestamp": 3,"name": "name 1"}, 
    {"timestamp": 4,"name": "name 2"},
    {"timestamp": 5,"name": "name 1"}, 
    {"timestamp": 6,"name": "name 2"},
    {"timestamp": 7,"name": "name 1"}, 
    {"timestamp": 8,"name": "name 2"},
    {"timestamp": 9,"name": "name 1"}, 
    {"timestamp": 10,"name": "name 2"}
    ]};
    
    
    const filteredData = object.main.filter(o => o.timestamp >= 4 && o.timestamp <= 6);
    
    console.log(filteredData);
```

Comment: It's working properly, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As explained by @ben Beck in the comment, you are looking for [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return the filtered array and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/includes) to find the needed timestamps

```js
var object = {"main": [
    {"timestamp": "1am","name": "name 1"},
    {"timestamp": "2am","name": "name 2"},
    {"timestamp": "3am","name": "name 1"}, 
    {"timestamp": "4am","name": "name 2"},
    {"timestamp": "5am","name": "name 1"}, 
    {"timestamp": "6am","name": "name 2"},
    {"timestamp": "7am","name": "name 1"}, 
    {"timestamp": "8am","name": "name 2"},
    {"timestamp": "9am","name": "name 1"}, 
    {"timestamp": "10am","name": "name 2"}
    ]};
const from = 4; //4am
const to = 6; //6am

//generates the list of timestamps needed
const neededTimestamps = [];
for(let i = 4; i <= 6; i++){
  neededTimestamps.push(i + 'am');
}
console.log("Needed timestamps", JSON.stringify(neededTimestamps));  
 
const filtered = object.main.filter(o => neededTimestamps.includes(o.timestamp));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: I get an error :-<--- Last few GCs --->


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node_module_register
 2: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 4: v8::internal::Heap::CreateFillerObjectAt
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedDoubleArray
     I also used  node --max-old-space-size=4096 yourFile.js

Comment: Perhaps this is linked to another part of your code

Comment: I get another error :- TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: It means that `object.main` is undefined. Be sure that you are calling the correct array. This is a simple and clear error. You should try to fix it yourself instead of directly asking for help. It will help you to manage error in the future and debug them yourself

Answer (score 0):

Use filter method to filter data from array

```js
var object = {"main": [
    {"timestamp": "1am","name": "name 1"},
    {"timestamp": "2am","name": "name 2"},
    {"timestamp": "3am","name": "name 1"}, 
    {"timestamp": "4am","name": "name 2"},
    {"timestamp": "5am","name": "name 1"}, 
    {"timestamp": "6am","name": "name 2"},
    {"timestamp": "7am","name": "name 1"}, 
    {"timestamp": "8am","name": "name 2"},
    {"timestamp": "9am","name": "name 1"}, 
    {"timestamp": "10am","name": "name 2"}
    ]};

const filtered = object.main.filter(o => o.timestamp === '4am' || 
o.timestamp === '5am' || o.timestamp === '6am');

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: You should add more information to explain your answer - For example: the function that you are using