# Filtering an array with Multiple Condition of queries from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have 2 Arrays. One containing data like this.

```
[{_id:123, Name: Mike, City: London},
{_id:456, Name: John, City: New York}]
```

And another array having queries like this.

```
[{fieldName: Name, operator: ===, value: Mike, logicalOperator: ||},
{fieldName: City, operator: !==, value: London, logicalOperator: ||},]
```

How can we filter first array with second one.

Something like

```
data.filter(item => query.map(q => item.query.fieldName q.operator q.value)
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: 1) What is the expected output 2) It gives error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ===`

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53850431/1641941) helps.

Comment: @brk , Expected out put is to display object (or objects) based on queries. Like if query is Name = Mike || City = New York  in this case both objects will be displayed.

Comment: Iram, the content of your last comment (about the expected output) should be in the question itself...

Comment: The purpose of `logicalOperator` is not clear, please provide some details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the `logicalOperator` and use either `some` or `every` and filter the array with the operands and operator.

```js
function getFilter(filter) {
    var op = {
            '&&': (a, b) => a && b,
            '||': (a, b) => a || b,
            '!==': (a, b) => a !== b,
            '===': (a, b) => a === b,
            '<>': (a, b) => a !== b,
            '>=': (a, b) => a >= b,
//            'startsWith': (a, b) => a.startsWith(b), // see default example below
//            'endsWith': (a, b) => a.endsWith(b),
//            'includes': (a, b) => a.includes(b),
            default: k => (a, b) => a[k](b)            // works for any method
        },                                             // with this pattern
        fn = Array.prototype.reduce.bind(filter);

    return o => fn((a, { fieldName, operator, value, logicalOperator }, i) => {
        var b = (op[operator] || op.default(operator))(o[fieldName], value)
        if (!i) return b;
        return op[logicalOperator](a, b);
    }, undefined);
}

var data = [{ _id: 123, Name: 'Mike', City: 'London' }, { _id: 456, Name: 'John', City: 'New York' }],
    filter = [{ fieldName: 'Name', operator: '===', value: 'Mike', logicalOperator: '||' }, { fieldName: 'City', operator: '!==', value: 'London', logicalOperator: '||' }],
    result = data.filter(getFilter(filter))

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanx. This is what i am looking for. What if logicalOperator is null at last object of filter array (user can press Search instead of continuing with And / Or), and if op is different (can b ===, or !==) so how to adjust this in type variable. Appreciate your help.

Comment: ad1: the logical operator makes only sense between two conditions. if you need a real check to the end of the array of filters, then you need a different approach (and, of course some sense of operator precedence, if wanted). for this case, you need to state some cases. ad2, this is more or less the same as ad1, you need an expression which glues all conditions. please add some use cases and the wanted result (btw, the last logical operand goes void.)

Comment: Search operators in dropdown list are as  ===, !==, <>, >=, startsWith, includes, endsWith .  And if i don't remove || operator from last object, it gave me error "Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined"

Comment: e.g var data = [{ _id: 123, Name: 'Mike', City: 'London' }, { _id: 456, Name: 'John', City: 'New York' }, { _id: 789, Name: 'David', City: 'Sydney' }],                                          filter = [{ fieldName: 'Name', operator: '===', value: 'Mike', logicalOperator: '||' }, { fieldName: 'City', operator: 'includes', value: 'Syd', logicalOperator: '' }],                        Output will be      [{ _id: 123, Name: 'Mike', City: 'London' },{ _id: 789, Name: 'David', City: 'Sydney'}]

Answer (score 2):

You could use functions to represent the comparison operations:

```
[{
  fieldName: "Name",
  operator: (a, b) => a === b,
  value: "Mike", 
  logicalOperator: (a, b) => a || b,
}, {
  fieldName: "City",
  operator: (a, b) => a !== b, 
  value: "London", 
  logicalOperator: (a, b) => a || b
}]
```

Then it is as easy as:

```
data.filter(item => query.reduce((acc, q) => q.locicalOperator(
   acc,
   q.operator(item[q.fieldName], q.value)
), true);
```

Comment: I think you should reduce query: `query.reduce((result,q)=>result&&q.operator(item[query.fieldName], q.value),true)` or use Array.prototype.every: `query.every(q=>q.operator(item[query.fieldName], q.value))`

Comment: @Jonas Wims, i provided search inputs as follows.....                                                           One Input box for FieldName.                                                                                                 Then is dropdown list of operators. So user will select options like ===, !== , startsWith, endsWith etc, so after selection get its value and store into as operator into object.

Comment: @Iram then map the input string to the related operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore the javascript's eval function for this kind of operations. 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

For example:

```
function myFunction() {
  var a = "'nice'";

  var expr = a + " === 'eval'";

  console.log(a);
  var res = eval(expr) + "<br>";
  //res = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little off-topic, but I wanted to share another way of writing queries using [prefix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation).

```js
operators = {
  "has" : function (v) { return this.hasOwnProperty(v); },
  "var" : function (v) { return this[v]; },
  "and" : (a, b) => a && b,
  "or" : (a, b) => a || b,
  "eq" : (a, b) => a === b
};

data = [
  { id : 789, name : "London", city : "London" },
  { id : 123, name : "John", city : "London" },
  { id : 234, name : "Mike", city : "London" },
  { id : 345, name : "John", city : "New York" },
  { id : 456, name : "Jack", city : "New York" },
  { id : 567, name : "James", city : "New York" },
  { id : 678, key : "value" }
];

queries = [
  "key === \"value\"", [
    "EQ", "VAR", "key", "value"
  ],
  "name === \"John\"", [
    "EQ", "VAR", "name", "John"
  ],
  "name === city", [
    "AND",
    "AND", "HAS", "name", "HAS", "city",
    "EQ", "VAR", "name", "VAR", "city"
  ],
  "name === \"John\" || city === \"London\"", [
    "OR",
    "EQ", "VAR", "name", "John",
    "EQ", "VAR", "city", "London"
  ],
  "id === 234 || name === \"John\" && city === \"New York\"", [
    "OR",
    "EQ", "VAR", "id", 234,
    "AND",
    "EQ", "VAR", "name", "John",
    "EQ", "VAR", "city", "New York"
  ],
  "city === \"New York\" && (name === \"John\" || name === \"James\")", [
    "AND",
    "EQ", "VAR", "city", "New York",
    "OR",
    "EQ", "VAR", "name", "John",
    "EQ", "VAR", "name", "James"
  ]
];

for (i = 0; i < queries.length; i += 2) {
  console.log(queries[i]);
  console.log(data.filter(
    (query => item => evaluate.call(item, query))(queries[i + 1])
  ).map(function (x) {
    return JSON.stringify(x);
  }).join("\n"));
}

function evaluate (expr) {
  var i, j, op, args, stack = [];
  for (i = expr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    op = typeof expr[i] !== "string" ? undefined : (
      operators[expr[i].toLowerCase()]
    );
    if (op === undefined) {
      stack.push(expr[i]);
    } else {
      args = new Array(op.length);
      for (j = 0; j < op.length; j++) {
        args[j] = stack.pop();
      }
      stack.push(op.apply(this, args));
    }
  }
  return stack.pop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your addition. Will this work out if Data contains objects of different key-value pairs? like [{id:234, name:'Mike'},{id:111, city:'London'}, {id:222, country:'Aus'}]             Also when i m running the same code, getting error "operators is not defined"

Comment: @IramAkhtar Yes it will work with any object, and no, you are not running the same code :-)