# High performance methods for selecting table data (array of objects) JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapreduce

I am trying to optimize selecting data from a large table (an array of objects).

I'd like to save multiple values from a single row and then write to localStorage.

```
let customerTable = [
  {
    "customer": "Apple Computers",
    "contact": "Steve Jobs",
    "id": 1,
    "city": "Cupertino"
  },
  {
    "customer": "Microsoft",
    "contact": "Bill Gates",
    "id": 2,
    "city": "Redmond"
  },
  {
    "customer": "Microsoft",
    "contact": "Satya Nadella",
    "id": 3,
    "city": "Redmond"
  }
]

let selectedRow = customerTable
  .filter(i => { return i.customer === selectedCustomer })
  .filter(i => { return i.contact === selectedContact })

let id = selectedRow
  .map(a => a.id)                                                  
  .filter((item, pos, self) => {return self.indexOf(item) === pos}) // Remove duplicates

let city = selectedRow
  .map(a => a.city)
  .filter((item, pos, self) => { return self.indexOf(item) === pos })
```

Is there a more performant method to selecting multiple values from a data model of this type?

Comment: You're chaining four array operations there. You could combine them, so you only go over the array once, not four times. That can be done manually (mash the code together), semi-manually (compose the functions together), automatically handles (lazy evaluation, transducers). It's hard to say what's the most performant way here, though, and it also depends on the codebase and if you're willing to use other libraries or implement some functionality yourself and other factors.

Comment: To expand on @VLAZ, could let selectedRow = customerTable
  .filter(i => { return i.customer === selectedCustomer })
  .filter(i => { return i.contact === selectedContact }) not be written as a AND operation .filter(i => { return i.customer === selectedCustomer &&  i.contact === selectedContact }) (Just as an example. You can probably do the same with all of your chained loops.)

Comment: @CalIrvine just do every single operation inside a single `.reduce`, so you would go over the array two times in total, instead of six. You could even condense it to a single run by doing both the `id` and the `city` logic at once and assign items to two different arrays.

Comment: @CalIrvine Interesting comment regarding the AND operation.

Comment: @VLAZ Could you show me what the reduce pattern would look like?

Comment: How about one or multiple indices? How often does your data change? Searching a short list should always be faster than searching a long one

Comment: @Thomas The data changes about once per minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter looks fine; however you could [filter with composing functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53850431/1641941).

Getting unique values can be optimized using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
let id = [...selectedRow.reduce(
  (result,item)=>result.add(item.id)
  ,new Set()
)]
```

Or as Jonas pointed out (so you don't need reduce):

```
let id = [...new Set(
  selectedRow.map(item=>item.id)
)]
```

Comment: I agree to your main point that optimizing the duplicate filtering is the thing to do here, but I'd just do `[...new Set(selectedRow.map(it => it.id))]`

Comment: @JonasWilms You're correct, providing an array to Set constructor would be simpler and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

In general you want to reduce the number of loops you have, so you shouldn't use multiple array operation when the same result can be achieved with one loop. The operations you're performing can be optimized.

```
let selectedRow = customerTable
    .filter(i => { return i.customer === selectedCustomer })
    .filter(i => { return i.contact === selectedContact });
```

loops through the array twice. It can be rewritten to loop through the array only one time as

```
let selectedRow = customerTable
    .filter(i => {return i.customer === selectedCustomer && i.contact === selectedContact});
```

The other example also utilize multiple array operations that can be performed in one loop.

Your current code will compute `selectedRow` as all matching customers and contact pairs in an array and `city` and `id` are also arrays of the the unique cities and ids. This can be performed in a single loop as.

```
// using Set for performance as suggested by @HMR
let selectedRows = [], cities = new Set(), ids = new Set();
for (let i = 0; i = customerTable.length; i++) {
    if (customerTable[i].customer === selectedCustomer && customerTable[i].contact === selectedContact) {
        selectedRows.push(customerTable[i]);
        // include uniqueness contraint on cities and ids
        cities.add(customerTable[i].city);
        ids.add(customerTable[i].id);
    }
}
```

Depending on where you're getting your data if you can refactor it, you would get better performance on this search with a hashmap (object) with customer, contact, or some combination of both as the keys.

Comment: `someArray.filter().filter()` does not loop through the someArray twice. Result of the first filter is given to the second one so you didn't optimize much with your "optimization"

Comment: @HMR The optimization removed all the looping of the second call to `filter` and reduce the overhead of a function call. In high performance code as the question is indicating this is, all time savings even small are important

Comment: I think OP wanted to filter a large array and get *unique* ids and cities from the filtered result. Biggest gain is probably not using indexOf when trying to get unique value from a (possibly very large) filtered result. One way to optimize getting unique values is to use reduce with Set. Also I think is far more important to write composible/re-usable code that performs enough so it's not a noticeable problem.

Comment: @HMR excellent point, my assumption from the question was that the OP wanted performant code even at the cost of readability and re-usability, but I could be entirely wrong. I updated my answer to use Set. With enough searches the optimal solution may be to put the entire array in a Map up front and then do lots of fast searches.

Answer (score 0):

```
let customerTable = [
    {
        "customer": "Apple Computers",
        "contact": "Steve Jobs",
        "id": 1,
        "city": "Cupertino"
    },
    {
        "customer": "Microsoft",
        "contact": "Bill Gates",
        "id": 2,
        "city": "Redmond"
    },
    {
        "customer": "Microsoft",
        "contact": "Bill Gates",
        "id": 2,
        "city": "Redmond"
    }
]

let selectedCustomer = "Microsoft";
let selectedContact = "Bill Gates"; 

// [[id], [city]]
let results = customerTable.reduce((_i, _j) => { 
    if(!(_j.customer === selectedCustomer && _j.contact === selectedContact)) return _i;
    _i[0].push(_j.id);
    _i[1].push(_j.city);
    return _i; 
}, [[], []])
.map((v) => v.filter((i, j, a) => a.indexOf(i) === j));
```

last `.map`, `.filter` is for removing duplicated items (as of question) if you are sure there will not be any duplicates you can remove this line,

if there no need for other filtering and no duplicates, the code will look like

```
let results = customerTable.reduce((_i, _j) => { 
    if(!(_j.customer === selectedCustomer && _j.contact === selectedContact)) return _i;
    _i[0] = _j.id;
    _i[1] = _j.city;
    return _i; 
}, [-1, ""])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, why do you have duplicate IDs? Ain't the point of IDs that they are unique?

---

Aside from optimizing the actual code, you can also optimize the data you are filtering; as mentioned in the comment, it's faster to search a short list than a long one.

So if your Array changes relatively rare compared to the searches you do on the data, it may be worth to create one or more indices. This could be as simple as:

```
let ixCustomer = new Map();
const ixCustomerKey = item => item.customer.charAt(0).toLowerCase();

const add = (index, key, value) => {
  if(index.has(key)) index.get(key).push(value) 
  else index.set(key, [value]));
}

for(let item of customerTable){
  add(ixCustomer, ixCustomerKey(item), item);      
}
```

so that if you search you don't have to search `customerTable` but only a subset, which if you choose the right way to index the data, should be way smaller than the original Array.

```
let id = new Set();
let city = new Set();

let arr = ixCustomer.get(ixCustomerKey(selectedCustomer)) || [];

for(let item of arr){
  if(item.customer !== selectedCustomer || item.company !== selectedCompany) continue;

  id.add(item.id);
  city.add(item.city);
}
```

But you need to know wether this overhead is it worth, for your data and your use-case.